# IFS splitting issue

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am using the following line at the beginning of a bash shell script:

```
IFS=':#:'
```

But it is not separating fields with :#:, only with colon. What is the issue?

**EDIT:**

This is my data in text file:

```
f:#:0
c:#:Test C
s:#:test S
ctype:#:0
a:#:test A
t:#:10:02:03
r:#:test r

f:#:0
c:#:Test C1
s:#:test S1
ctype:#:1
a:#:test A1
t:#:00:02:22
r:#:test r

f:#:20
c:#:Test C
s:#:test S
ctype:#:2
a:#:test A1
t:#:00:02:03
r:#:test r
```

... and I am reading it using the following code:

```
IFS=':#:'   
while read -r key value; do
 .....
done < "$FileName"
```

Comment: Note that in this case you don't really *need* a multicharacter separator - you can treat the `#` as a *field* and simply discard it e.g. `while IFS=: read -r key _ value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @heemayl the problem is that IFS doesn't treat the whole string as the separator, it treats each char as a individual separator. `awk` however is able to use a string as a delim.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r key value
do 
   printf 'key %-7s val %s\n' "$key" "$value" 
done < <(awk -F ':#:' '{print $1" "$2}' $FileName )

key f       val 0
key c       val Test C
key s       val test S
key ctype   val 0
key a       val test A
key t       val 10:02:03
key r       val test r
key         val 
key f       val 0
key c       val Test C1
key s       val test S1
key ctype   val 1
key a       val test A1
key t       val 00:02:22
key r       val test r
key         val 
key f       val 20
key c       val Test C
key s       val test S
key ctype   val 2
key a       val test A1
key t       val 00:02:03
key r       val test r
```

Comment: What if i am using this in while loop as seperator and reading mulitple lines from files with this seperator?

Comment: If you're looking for a comprehensive answer we are going to need more information to go on. Post a code sample of what you have with some example input and expected output.

Comment: edited in question..see now

Comment: @BhumiShah updated my answer

Comment: Not working. getting error  Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: @BhumiShah what shell are you using? At the top of your script do you have a shebang? If so what is it, the io redirection above is for bash so you would need the first line of your script to be `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: This command "/bin/bash --version" is giving me  version 4.3.30(1)

Comment: @BhumiShah make sure your first line is a shebang for bash. i.e. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Actually if i run it using bash test.sh, it is working but if i run using sh test.sh getting error

Comment: #!/bin/bash is there already but an issue is if I run using sh test.sh getting the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50816/discussion-between-bhumi-shah-and-zachary-brady).

Answer (score 2):

`IFS` does not use multiple characters (or a range) as separator; each character in `IFS` is treated as a field separator.

From `man bash`:

> IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting
>   after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin
>   command.  The default value is 
>      `<space><tab><newline>`.

Comment: Is there any way for multiple characters separator?